# Need help for SQL select query for this two table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, subquery

Table Capture image : http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/6213/99730337.jpg

```
------------ PositionTable------------
ID    ContentFK   Position
11     100               1
12     101               1
13     104               2
14     102               2
15     103               2
16     105               3
17     106               3
18     107               2


----------Content Table ------------
ContentID   UpdateDate  Title
100          11.10.2009    Aol
101          12.10.2009    Microsoft
102          12.10.2009    e-Bay
103          12.11.2009    google
104          16.11.2009    novell
105          17.11.2009    asus
106          16.11.2009    nokia
107          11.11.2009    samsung
```

Who can help me to the question between the two tables
My scenario.

Sort by number as Position 1,2,3. However, a number of the groups to list only one record
(order by Position ASC (Position: 1,2,3)

With PositionTable.ContentFK = ContentTable.ContentID
by UpdateDate of last update in ContentTablo

How I can get list same as result.

```
p.Postion     p.ID            p.ContentFK     c.UpdateDate      c.Title

1             12              101             12.10.2009        Microsoft 
2             13              104             16.11.2009        novell 
3             16              105             17.11.2009        asus
```

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

**EDIT**: Original code was because I thought your dates were MM.DD.YYYY. Realized your dates were DD.MM.YYYY and adjusted code accordingly.

**EDIT 2**: Changed answer based on feedback for UpdateDate datatype.

```
;with cteMaxDate as (
    select p.Position, MAX(c.UpdateDate) as MaxDate
        from PositionTable p
            inner join ContentTable c
                on p.ContentFK = c.ContentID
        group by p.Position
)
select p.Position, p.ID, p.ContentFK, c.UpdateDate, c.Title
    from cteMaxDate m
        inner join PositionTable p
            on m.Position = p.Position
        inner join ContentTable c
            on p.ContentFK = c.ContentID
                and m.MaxDate = c.UpdateDate
```

Comment: +1 - Good catch on the date -- I thought that were MM.DD.YYYY at first too. Assuming it's a string, one couldn't just do a MAX on the UpdateDate as it stands, which is what you've covered.

Comment: Thank you. I want to gave a complete result.

Comment: UpdateDate type : SmallDateTime

Comment: Updated my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery's a bit ugly (and correlated), but this is the simplest way I can think of doing it.

Assuming your UpdateDate column is DATETIME - otherwise you'll have to do something like Joe did (or, better, change the column to DATETIME :-)

```
select p.Position
    ,p.ID
    ,p.ContentFK
    ,c.UpdateDate
    ,c.Title
from PositionTable p
join ContentTable c
    on p.ContentFK = c.ContentID
    and c.UpdateDate = (select max(ic.UpdateDate) from ContentTable ic
                            join PositionTable ip
                                on ip.ContentFK = ic.ContentID
                            where ip.Position = p.Position)
order by p.Position
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select Position,  ID, ContentFK, UpdateDate, Title
from (
select  p.Position,
    p.ID,
    p.ContentFK,
    c.UpdateDate,
    c.Title,
    row_number() over (partition by p.Position order by p.Position, c.UpdateDate desc) as num
from    Position p inner join
    Content c on p.ContentFK = c.ContentId ) a
where   num = 1
```

Comment: What if Google had a date of '12.11.2010'?

Comment: I'm assuming it's a datetime field here and that the dodgy string format is a seperate issue. it should of course be YYYYMMDD to be totally safe.

Comment: Return error : Invalid object name 'Position'. i can't fix it

Comment: It's because I named your tables Position and Content, you need to rename it to PositionTable if that's what you called it.